# Why do I get false from equals method?

Tags: java

I created custom class called Experement.I override equals and hashCode Object's methods.

The idea is to compare fields of the class and not references as default behave.

Here is my custom Experement class(and you can see overrided methods):

```
public class Experiment {

  private   DNAChain[] Chains; // Chains found in the experiment
  private    int   counter; // next  chain  index

 public DNAChain[] getChains() {
      return Chains;
 }

 public void setChains(DNAChain[] chains) {
      Chains = chains;
 }

  public  Experiment (int  n) {
      Chains  = new DNAChain[n];
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      Experiment that = (Experiment)o;

      if (counter != that.counter) return false;

      //The two arrays are considered equal if
      //both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding
      //pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal
      return Arrays.equals(Chains, that.Chains);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
     int result = Arrays.hashCode(Chains);
     result = 31 * result + counter;
     return result;
 }
```

}

And here is y DNAChain class:

```
public class DNAChain {
    private  String  Chain;
    private    boolean natural;

    public String getChain() {
        return Chain;
    }

    public  DNAChain (String  Chain, boolean natural) {
        this.Chain = Chain;
        this.natural = natural;
    }    
}
```

And here is main method were I call overrided equals methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DNAChain[] chainArr1  = new DNAChain[]{new DNAChain("agact",true),
                                          new DNAChain("ctgacc",true)};

    DNAChain[] chainArr2  = new DNAChain[]{new DNAChain("agact",true),
                                           new DNAChain("ctgacc",true)};


    Experiment experiment1 = new Experiment(5);
    Experiment experiment2 = new Experiment(5);

    experiment1.setChains(chainArr1);
    experiment2.setChains(chainArr2);

    boolean isEqueal = experiment1.equals(experiment2)
    System.out.println(isEqueal);
}
```

I can't understand why in this row:

```
boolean isEqueal = experiment1.equals(experiment2);
```

isEqual is `false` while  two Experiment instances has the same properties value?

Comment: Because you've not overridden equals in `DNAChain`.

Comment: ... or in short: `new DNAChain("agact",true).equals(new DNAChain("agact",true)) == false`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not implement the `equals()` method on `DNAChain`.
Even though a `DNAChain` object contains the same `String` they will only be equal if they're the same instance, as the code is currently.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.equals` will return true iff the lengths of the arrays are equal, and the corresponding elements are null, or equal according to the elements' `equals` method.

If you don't override `equals` in `DNAChain`, they are compared by identity, since that is how `equals` is defined on its superclass, `Object`. Since you create separate instances of `DNAChain` for the two arrays, they will not be equal.

Override `equals` (and `hashCode`) in `DNAChain`.

Comment: Andy  thanks for post.As I understood Arrays.equals() compare corresponding elements in two arrays references?